# I uninstalled my apache2 from Ubuntu, now I am unable to reinstall it

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I Uninstall my apach2 from Ubuntu because it looks not working now I tried to install it again with the command `sudo apt install apache2`

and I can see the below errors

```
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.7.0-8ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1_1.6.1-5ubuntu4.22.04.2_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.6.1-5ubuntu4.22.04.2_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-ldap_1.6.1-5ubuntu4.22.04.2_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7_all.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/ssl-cert/ssl-cert_1.1.2_all.deb  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried `apt-get update` and now there are below warnings

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And when I run the below command it gives error

> sudo systemctl status apache2

**Error: Unit apache2.service could not be found.**

and after

```
sudo ufw app list
```

It says:
Available applications:

- OpenSSH
- iperf

So now I am unable to install apache2 on Ubuntu

Comment: Try `sudo apt install apache2` again, edit your question and add the exact error message that you get.

Comment: Just because you uninstalled it and installed it again does not mean you fixed the problem that kept it from working before.

Comment: @Jos I edited my question

Comment: I doubt whether `mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com` is a proper and trusted mirror. What is your usual Ubuntu mirror?

Comment: Sorry @Jos I am almost a newbie to Ubuntu So don't know about mirrors. I was following the tutorial somewhere on a site.

Comment: You install new software from a mirror, a large repository of Ubuntu software. That is a web server usually called xxx.ubuntu.com, where xxx depends on the country you are in. The name of this mirror is entered in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and in other `*.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Apparently, Ali Baba has been messing with your `sources.list` file so all your installed software comes from an untrusted server. Go through the `*.list` files mentioned above, and change (using `sudo nano`)  all occurrences of this `mirror.cloud.aliyuncs.com` server to the mirror for your country.

Comment: I mentioned Ali Baba, not as a joke, but because the domain `aliyuncs.com` is actually registered to Ali Baba Cloud Computing (Beijing) Co., Ltd.

Comment: LOL (re Ali Baba) @Jos might be easier for OP to run `software-properties-gtk` and choose a mirror from there instead of editing sources files manually.

Comment: @Raffa You are right, that is easier. But I would want to know which of my files were affected / hacked, wouldn't you? :-)

Comment: @Jos Fair enough ... Good luck with that

Comment: @Jos You just saved my life, I just edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list`  and changed the mirrors accordingly and It works. O My God.

Comment: I will expand my comments to a proper answer. Please tick the check mark next to it if you feel I have sufficiently answered your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason that we don't know, the name of the mirror server for your installation has been changed to an untrusted mirror called `mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com`. That is not a regular Ubuntu mirror, and certainly didn't come with the installation of your Ubuntu system. This server isn't even responding at this moment.

You can change it back to a trusted mirror, either manually by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and each `*.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`; or by using the graphic utility `software-properties-gtk`, as recommended by @Raffa.

A trusted mirror is usually a web server called `xxx.ubuntu.com` where `xxx` is a code specific to your country.

However, after installing something, check back to the `*.list` files and see if they haven't changed back. If your system was somehow hacked, it may be hacked again. If that is the case, nothing less than a complete reinstall is safe.

Comment: Your solution worked. I just edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file manually and changed the mirrors accordingly, and after that, I installed apache2 and it installed correctly.

Comment: There are vps/server providers that host their own internal mirrors for customers (internal network, so, fast) but don't want the world to use them, so don't add them to an official list. Their initial setup typically points to those internal mirrors, so a situation like this isn't that rare.

Comment: True, but in a case like that I think @KashifSohail should be able to find out how and why `mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com` was set as the system's mirror server. If they can't, then this looks quite suspicious and it would be prudent to react as though the system has been hacked.

Comment: mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com is the official Alibaba cloud mirror, according to https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/ecs/user-guide/add-a-software-repository - it may just be broken.