# After installing apache2 it gives 403 Forbidden error

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, sudo, webserver

I installed the apache2 server on Ubuntu and after success, when I tried to hit the URL to check whether it worked or not it threw `403 Forbidden` error instead of showing Apache's default page.
I restarted the apache server by running the `sudo systemctl restart apache2` command
and when I ran  `sudo systemctl restart httpd` command it gave the below error.

```
Failed to restart httpd.service: Unit httpd.service not found.
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't install apache2. Try running `sudo apt install apache2`

Comment: Since you [previously uninstalled apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1505667/i-uninstalled-my-apache2-from-ubuntu-now-i-am-unable-to-reinstall-it), It would be best to start from scratch. Run the following commands - `sudo apt purge apache2`  `sudo apt update`  `sudo apt install apache2`

Comment: ''sudo systemctl restart apache2''

Comment: @petep OP already tried that.

Comment: Also, What URL are you using? And what version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run `lsb_release -a` and [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1505677/edit) your question to include both of this information.